# Update rows in excel from another excel file based on PRODUCT CODE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with the following :

In the first excel file (with 500products) I have two columns :

```
PRODUCT CODE,

PRICE,
```

In another excel file (with 10000 products) I have 3 columns :

```
PRODUCT CODE,

PRODUCT NAME,

PRODUCT DESCRIPTION
```

In this second file there are additional 9500 products, which in this situation I will not need.
I need to update the first file - those 500 products - basically I need to add the data from the second file based on `PRODUCT CODE`.

By other words : Read the first `PRODUCT CODE` in file1, then find the same `PRODUCT CODE` in file2 then copy the `PRODUCT NAME` and `PRODUCT DESCRIPTION` and add these data to this row in file1. Continue to next `PRODUCT CODE` in file1 and do the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code writing service so it helps if you show what you have tried so far. take a look at VLOOKUPs this will help read the description in one table based on product code.

Comment: Agreed. VLOOKUP is exactly what you want. If you can't figure out how to make it work after looking at examples for a little while, come back and we'll help you correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the name and description is in columns C and D respectively in the 1st file, use the below formula,

```
C2=INDEX([abc.xlsx]Sheet1!A:C,MATCH(A2,[abc.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,0),2)
D2=INDEX([abc.xlsx]Sheet1!A:C,MATCH(A2,[abc.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,0),3)
```

These formulas read the data starting from A2(product code), search the same in abc.xlsx (2nd file) Sheet 1 and returns the name and description. The name and description in the 2nd file should be in columns B and C. Let me know if you need anything else.